Networkpolicy blocks ingress traffic unexpectedly
Here is the definition of the networkpolicy:
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchExpressions:
      - key: app.kubernetes.io/component
        operator: In
        values:
          - "backend"
          - "read"
          - "write"
          - "memcached-chunk"
          - "memcached-results"
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
  ingress:
    - from:
        - namespaceSelector:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/metadata.name
                operator: In
                values:
                  - "{{ .Release.Namespace }}"
                  - "ingress-nginx"
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 192.168.0.0/16
  egress:
    - {}

When I tried to access curl the API via ingress from 192.168.126.128, it timed out. And from the logs of nginx ingress-controller, I could see the same error:

2024/05/14 17:23:27 [error] 5437#5437: *6517485 upstream timed out
(110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream, client:
192.168.126.128, server: , request:
"GET /metrics HTTP/1.1", upstream:
"http://172.16.122.129:9150/metrics", host:
":80"

I am able to curl the API via http://172.16.122.129:9150/metrics from pod in the namespaces on the allowlist, but not from others.
The networkpolicy should allow the traffic from the ipblock, do I miss something? When I delete the networkpolicy, all traffic works.

@ joker57 I have provided comments based on your requirements . If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Looks like there is a configuration problem with the network policy definition you provided that is blocking unexpected traffic.There is an error in the in namespace selector from the access rule section.The double curly braces {{ .Release.Namespace } }  are  helm should be specified for charts, but by default, Kubernetes are not defined properly.
Sometimes, Kubernetes will not be able to set the value of {{ .Release.Namespace }} resulting in the empty namespace option. This will block all incoming traffic because none of the namespaces are explicitly set from the block.
To FIX the issue:
Ingress will now allow any pod from any namespace to enter the API just delete the entire namespace selection in the from stanza and receptive addresses selection of any for the same.
YAML:
ingress:
  - from:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 192.168.0.0/16

In case you only want access into the API to be restricted to pods from certain namespaces then replace {{ .Release.Namespace }} to your actual namespace name where your ingress controller is located.
After making the adjustments, reapply the network policy with kubectl apply-f< your-networkpolicy -file.yaml >. Try booting from the API with an IP address which allows you to get admission to ( 192.168.0.0/16 ) from the appropriate device pod namespace .You can now correctly access the API.

Thanks for the reply, but this config is part of my chart and I would like to populate the namespaceSelector automatically when the chart  is installed. I checked the value and confirmed which is populated as expected.

@ joker57 I understand which you want the namespace selector to be routinely populated with the namespace in which the chart is hooked up.Here are  tactics you can take to acquire this
Helm Chart presents functions like chart hooks and helm values to automate configurations at some stage in deployment.
There are helm libraries to be had that may simplify the system.Helm includes a library called kubeval for validating YAML documents.You could enlarge the installation system.This technique calls for extra superior helm know-how however offers more flexibility.

By using those techniques, you may ensure your network policy automatically  populates the namespace selector for the duration of chart installation,providing dynamic control over ingress

Even when helm chart is installed and I can retrieve the networkpolicy value via "kubectl get networkpolicy  -o yaml" to make sure the namespace is correctly populated, still the issue "Sometimes, Kubernetes will not be able to set the value of {{ .Release.Namespace }} resulting in the empty namespace option."? Then it might be a bug of helm?
